# Split unevenly a CSV file in multiple files in bash scripting

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a folder with few big csv files and I want to have a variable number of almost equally sized CSV files.

At the moment this is my even sized division implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

#copy header to all resulting files parts
head -n 1 $1_2021.csv | awk -v NPROC=$(nproc) '{ for (i = 0; i < NPROC; ++i) print $0 > "file_"i".csv" }'

#copy the data but the header for each file part
tail --silent -n+2 $1* | awk -v NPROC=$(nproc) '{ part = NR % NPROC; print $0 >> "file_"part".csv" }'
```

where `$1` is the version of the files, passed as parameter to the bash script, for instance `v1` or `v2`.
The output filenames are not relevant, currently `file_"i".csv` & `file_"part".csv` produce the same filenames, where `part` & `i` lay in this range: `(0, NPROC)`

Some samples of the file `v1_2020.csv` (semicolon delimited)

```
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y  
2020-01-02;r;n;4;119  
2020-01-02;y;n;56;130  
2020-01-03;y;n;3;153  
2020-01-03;r;n;46;192  
2020-01-03;b;n;20;241  
2020-01-04;w;n;1252;252  
2020-01-05;w;n;453;253  
2020-01-06;b;y;1;279  
2020-01-06;b;n;945;294
```

Table-wise looks like this:

| DATE | COLOUR | CLOSING | CHANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | r | n | 4 |
| 2020-01-02 | y | n | 56 |
| 2020-01-03 | y | n | 3 |
| 2020-01-03 | r | n | 46 |
| 2020-01-03 | b | n | 20 |
| 2020-01-03 | w | n | 1252 |
| 2020-01-05 | w | n | 453 |
| 2020-01-06 | b | y | 1 |
| 2020-01-06 | b | n | 945 |

I want to improve this division in such a way that it does not separate into different files the same dates. So it should take into account the `DATE` column within the CSV file.

### Current output with `NPROC=2`:

`file_1.csv`

```
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y  
2020-01-02;r;n;4;119  
2020-01-03;y;n;3;153  
2020-01-03;b;n;20;241  
2020-01-05;w;n;453;253  
2020-01-06;b;n;945;294
```

`file_2.csv`

```
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y  
2020-01-02;y;n;56;130  
2020-01-03;r;n;46;192  
2020-01-04;w;n;1252;252  
2020-01-06;b;y;1;279
```

### New output with `NPROC=2`:

Whatever type of uneven splitting into `NPROC` number of files such that it does not mix up dates into different files.
One date should be just into one file but a file shall contain multiple dates.

For instance, but any other type of splitting into `NPROC` number of files is fine if it respects the conditions above:

`file_1.csv`

```
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y  
2020-01-02;r;n;4;119  
2020-01-02;y;n;56;130  
2020-01-03;y;n;3;153  
2020-01-03;r;n;46;192  
2020-01-03;b;n;20;241
```

`file_2.csv`

```
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y  
2020-01-04;w;n;1252;252  
2020-01-05;w;n;453;253  
2020-01-06;b;y;1;279  
2020-01-06;b;n;945;294
```

Could you give me any hint regarding a possible solution without using Python but just bash scripting?

Comment: They are semicolon formatted @TedLyngmo

Comment: [edit] your question to replace those graphical tables with the raw CSV that you generated them from so that we can copy/paste those files to test a potential solution against so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
awk -F';' -v NPROC=2 '
    NR == 1 {head = $0; next}
    !($1 in dates) {
        n = (n + 1) % NPROC
        file = "out_" n ".csv"
        if (!(file in created)) {
            print head > file
            created[file]
        }
        dates[$1] = file
    }
    { print > dates[$1] }
' v1_2020.csv
```

Since NPROC = 2, two output files are created:

```sh
$ cat out_0.csv
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y
2020-01-03;y;n;3;153
2020-01-03;r;n;46;192
2020-01-03;b;n;20;241
2020-01-05;w;n;453;253

$ cat out_1.csv
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE;Y
2020-01-02;r;n;4;119
2020-01-02;y;n;56;130
2020-01-04;w;n;1252;252
2020-01-06;b;y;1;279
2020-01-06;b;n;945;294
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to split a csv and add a header to each split, you can do:

```
awk -v cnt=6 -F ';' 'FNR==1{header=$0; fn=1}
!(FNR%cnt){
    fn++
    print header >"file_" fn ".csv"
}
{print $0>"file_" fn ".csv"}' file
```

If you want to split contextually based on the date column (assuming already sorted):

```
awk -v sp=6 -v fn=1 -F ';' 'FNR==1{header=$0}
cnt++>sp && l1!=$1 {
    fn++
    cnt=0
    print header >"file_" fn ".csv"
}
{print $0>"file_" fn ".csv"; l1=$1}' file
```

Result of second here:

```
cat *.csv
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE
2020-01-02;r;n;4
2020-01-02;y;n;56
2020-01-03;y;n;3
2020-01-03;r;n;46
2020-01-03;b;n;20
2020-01-03;w;n;1252
DATE;COLOUR;CLOSING;CHANGE
2020-01-05;w;n;453
2020-01-06;b;y;1
2020-01-06;b;n;945
```

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, that won't work. First, it resets `fn` to 1 at the start of every file and thus repeatedly overwrites the same file. But also, the `print >` will overwrite the whole file with each row... that should be `>>`.

Comment: I want to split it in such a way that: 1) one date is contained just within a file part 2) a file part shall contain multiple dates.
This because I need to provide consistency to process these files afterwards in parallel.

Comment: @Guido: It would be helpful to show in your question what you WANT as output.

Answer (score 1):

First, processing CSV/TSV files with command-line tools can be tricky. The `awk` command is the go-to here, but it doesn't have built-in support for quoting; if you have a row like `column 1; "column 2 has a ';' in it";column 3`, then `awk -F';'` will see it as `$1="column 1"`, `$2="\"column to has a '"`, `$3="'in it\""`, `$4="column3"`.

If your data doesn't have anything like that, then it's pretty straightforward. First, you want to write each date to its own file:

```
 awk -F';'  '{print >>$1".csv"}'
```

That will get you files named after the date, like `2020-01-02.csv`.

Now you can merge those into NPROC files, and as long as you only merge whole files, you won't split data from a given date into multiple files. Here's one simple (and not necessarily elegant!) way to do that:

```
declare -i lines=$(cat *-*-*.csv | wc -l) chunk cur
(( chunk = lines / NPROC, cur = 1 ))
for f in *-*-*.csv; do
  cat "$f" >>"file_$cur.csv"
  if (( $(wc -l <"file_$cur.csv") >= chunk )); then
     (( cur += 1 ))
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Mark and yes, I should not have the issue you mentioned about the column names. Regarding your proposed solution, I wrote that one date should be only within one file but I also meant that one file may contain multiple dates, since the number of final files I want to output is given by `NPROC`.
Your solution fits my use case anyhow I believe, because this could be the 1st step and then as 2nd step I can merge into `NPROC` files those files created by your input (1st step).
Does it sound correct to you?